# How can I customize the caret?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to customize the caret in my forms, or a contenteditable (html5) element. How can I do so?

Comment: Show what you got so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408041/customizing-text-cursor-in-contenteditable-element

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can change the cursor using the cursor property, but there is only one caret available.
The only option would be to set a custom cursor using an image, but that is not supported in all browsers. More info here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html

Comment: How is this the right answer? The OP asks for a custom caret, and you link to a custom cursor?

Comment: The caret is a cursor - you can set the cursor to caret by setting cursor:text. So if you want a custom caret you need a custom cursor.

Comment: Setting `cursor:text` changes the mouse cursor to look like a caret. It doesn't change the caret that shows you where you're editing in a text field or content editable area