# Hide textarea text but not blinking cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

I am trying to emulate how twitter highlights users when they are @mentioned when composing a tweet.

I am using the [mentionsInput jQuery plugin](http://podio.github.com/jquery-mentions-input/). I want to change the color of the @screen_name instead of changing the background color as the plugin does by default.

Is there a way to color the @screen_name and still show the blinking cursor at the end?

I was able to do it but I need to hide the textarea text so it doesn't darken the CSS styled text over it... but then it hides the blinking cursor which I don't want to do.

See my jsFiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/thhbe/1/

OR see it...

Required: jQuery, Underscore.js and the plugin.

HTML:

```
<div><textarea id="tweet_textarea" class="mention textarea compose_text"></textarea></div>
```

JS:

```
/*
* Add handlers to HTML elements and set options....
*/
$('textarea.mention').mentionsInput({
    onDataRequest:function (mode, query, callback) {
        var data = [
            { id:1, name:'Kenneth Auchenberg', 'avatar':'http://goo.gl/SUCm1', 'type':'contact' },
            { id:2, name:'Jon Froda', 'avatar':'http://goo.gl/SUCm1', 'type':'contact' },
            { id:3, name:'Anders Pollas', 'avatar':'http://goo.gl/SUCm1', 'type':'contact' }
        ];

        data = _.filter(data, function(item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 });

        callback.call(this, data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess I'd need to know the reason you aren't just using `contenteditable`.

Comment: I have just begun researching that... I haven't been able to get the plugin to work with `contenteditable` so far. If I just do it on my own (writing all code from scratch) it seems like it will take a lot of time to get it working IE8+ because of the difficulty getting cursor position... But I am going down that path at the moment.

Comment: I spent some time trying different things and finally convinced myself the only option is to write your own caret. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408041/customizing-text-cursor-in-contenteditable-element has fully working code for a textarea.

Comment: @Plynx if you answer this question with an example or link pointing to how to use `contenteditable` I will accept that as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me is to use `contenteditable` http://html5demos.com/contenteditable. It does not appear that this is how twitter has done it for their tweet input (which has mentions highlighted) but I have given up on figuring out how they did it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a couple of years late, but hopefully I can provide an actual answer to your problem.

You (or the plug-in) have got the idea right... utilizing another element (the "facsimile element") which contains a styled version of the text in the `textarea`. There are just a couple of changes that need to be made:

1. The fascimile element is supposed to have the same dimensions (the element as a whole as well as its content area), shape, and position as the `textarea`
2. The fascimile element is supposed to be placed *underneath* the `textarea` rather than *on top* of it.
3. The background of the `textarea` is supposed to be made transparent.
4. The text and border of the fascimilie element is supposed to be made transparent.

I'm not sure how much of this is able to be done without modifying the plug-in, but once these changes are made, you shouldn't have to worry about the cursor disappearing since there will no longer be a need for you to hide the `textarea`.

You're not out of the woods just yet though, there is a lot more that needs to be done to make the solution robust.

So I'd recommend checking out [Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator), which is a jQuery plug-in that robustly implements the functionality you desire. Its source code is a well-structured, easy to follow, and copiously commented, so should you want to look at the code to understand how the plug-in, and Twitter's tagging utility by extension (most likely), work, you should have little trouble doing so.

One more thing, given i'm such a big proponent of transparency, I'd like to let you know that Mentionator is maintained by yours truly :) .

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and found it difficult to find a nice solution. I was implementing my own caret/cursor into the styled element with a span tag, this has some issues with splitting up words onto new lines however. But I found a solution that's pretty simple and seeing as this is the first thing on Google for this problem I'll share it, as this would have been ideal for me weeks ago if it was here! :)

As said, the solution is to have your styled element underneath the text input. You need to make the text input have a alpha=0 background and color. The color also hides the caret. But there's a CSS property specifically for the caret that you can use the unhide it:

```css
background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.0 );
color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.0 );
caret-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1.0 );
```