# Changing Caret Color in Contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

Can I change the caret color inside a content editable div. 
Cursor color is always same as text color, red in my case.
So my question is that is there a way to change the caret color to black?
    eg `caret-color:black`
HTML:

```
<div class="red" contenteditable="true"> hello </div>
```

css:

```
.red{
   color:red;
  }
```

[Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/01y5196b/)

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779354/assign-color-to-mouse-cursor-using-css . It might help u

Comment: No it wont .. my use case is different

Comment: Do you mean cursor or caret?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret) will help you.

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408041/customizing-text-cursor-in-contenteditable-element).

Comment: Sorry i need to change caret color

Comment: And i have used contenteditable div in my html

Comment: you are looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/8k1k0awb/131/ ?

Comment: It will not work in FF or IE :(

Comment: @Vishu238 are you looking for this **http://jsfiddle.net/01y5196b/3/** or what.?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Use modern CSS!

```
div {
    caret-color : black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok.here's the solution :)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avbVzx
**

```
<input id="a" type="text">
<input id="b" type="text">
#a{
color:black;
-webkit-text-fill-color: red;
}
#b{
color:red;
-webkit-text-fill-color: green;
}
}
```

**

Answer (score -1):

hi i think this may help you for your answer

```css
.red{  
    color:red;
}
.red:focus{  
    outline:red;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red" contenteditable="true"> hello </div>
```

here is the demo fiddle working code

**[Demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/01y5196b/3/)**

Comment: Did you get my problem??